# Passing two different instances of a service down to two different instances of a component, one through a router-outlet and one through a MatDialog

Tags: angular, typescript, design-patterns, angular-router

**Fully rephrased question**:

I tried to simplify the problem, cause I understand the way I initially wrote it down is pretty convoluted; what follows is a simpler representation of the problem, albeit a slightly different representation of the problem.

I need a way to create two instances of a service in a top level component (namely the “app” component), and to pass each instance down to two different instances of another component (namely the "Client" component):

- The first instance of the "Client" component will be rendered within a `<router-outlet>`;
- The second instance of the "Client" component will be rendered within a MatDialog;

The service itself will just hold two methods and two observables in order to achieve parent-child communication, and implementation shouldn’t really matter in this case, but it would go something like this:

```
interface ChildInput {
    someData: number;
}

interface ParentInput {
    someData: string;
}

@Injectable
export class ComService {

    pushToChild(data: ParentInput) {
        // code to push data to the "child" observable
    }

    pushToParent(data: ChildInput) {
        // code to push data to the "parent" observable
    }

    // code to instantiate two observables, one for the parent to subscribe to and one for the child to subscribe to

}
```

What should be noted though, is that **I need to track down which “child” component is sending which data**; hence a shared instance of the service won’t work in this case.

Here's how the top-level component's template is structured:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/new-client']">
    New client
</a> <!-- this will render the "Client" component within router-outlet -->

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<button (click)="openClientPopup()">
    Add new client
</button> <!-- this will render the "Client" component within a MatDialog instance created by the openClientPopup() method -->
```

As I said creating a singleton instance at the top level component and injecting it into the "child" module the classic way won't work, because each instance of the "child" module will exchange data with the parent that should be bound, in the parent, to that specific instance of the component itself, and tracking down the sender by using some sort of id or something like that *feels* unnecessarily convoluted (It might not be though if that's the only way to go about doing it; I really don't know, and that's why I'm asking into first place);

On the other hand, while I could easily pass a service instance down to a component rendered within a MatDialog (there are actually multiple ways to do it), I'm not aware of a way to pass an instance of a service down to a component rendered within a `<router-outlet>`.

Any suggestion?

Comment: provide: 'serviceA': useClass: ComService and the same for another service. But you can use one service where you can establish separated channel for each communication

Comment: @yurzui Thanks, I don't think I'm understanding what you're suggesting though, how would I go about guessing which service to use in the child component in that case?

Comment: You can recognize the context: whether it was rendered through router or through dialog: `class ClientComponent { constructor(@Optional() private outlet: RouterOutlet) {` For component rendered through dialog `outlet` will be null

Comment: You can also pass any value you want to ClientComponent. I guess you know how to do it for MatDialog. For component rendered within router-outlet you can listen to `activate` event and recognize your component. `<router-outlet (activate)="outletActivated($event)">` and in ts `outletActivated(comp: any) {
    if (comp instanceof ClientComponent) {
      // pass any value
    }
  }`

Answer (score 1):

Provide the service directly to the parent using the `providers` parameter. Then Angular will inject that same instance into its children via their constructor.

##### Parent

```js
@Component({
  providers: [MyService]
})
class MyParentComponent {
    constructor(private myService: MyService)
}
```

##### Child

```js
@Component({})
class MyChildComponent {
    constructor(private myService: MyService)
}
```

### Edit:

So you are saying you want one parent, two children, two services; parent and respective children can share their service? If so, you can use a factory function.

##### Parent Component

```js
@Component({
    providers: [{
        provide: MyService,
        useFactory: () => (id: string) => new MyService(id)
    }]
})
export class ParentComponent {

    public service_a: MyService;
    public service_b: MyService;

    constructor(@Inject(MyService) myService: any) {
        this.service_a = myService('A');
        this.service_b = myService('B');
    }
}
```

##### Child Component

```js
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() service: MyService

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.service.log();
    }
}
```

##### Service

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

    constructor(private id: string) { }

    log() {
        console.log(this.id);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I said a singleton instance won’t work; I need two different instances in order to track down which child is sending which data, or at least an easy way to track the sender, although even inplementing an “id system” feels kinda cumbersome to me, and I hoped someone would come up with a smoother way.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but how do you pass the first instance to the component inside the router-outlet? @Input won’t work there (and you can’t send data to a component inside a MatDialog using @Input() either, although I could circumvent the issue with the MatDialog by other means ). Not an easy task overall :)

Comment: I mean, I’m stuck with this share service solution, but what I’m after in general is a way for the parent to communicate with the child and vice-versa; if it has to be something different than I’ll let it be. Problem is the type of input / output data eill be complex (an interface), and AFAIK you can’t pass an interface to a component rendered in a router-outlet without using a service. I may be wrong on this one though.

Comment: On the road atm, so not online much, sorry. You can definitely pass whatever data you like to a Mat Dialog. I completely overlooked the router piece, no idea how... I'd start to question your approach if you're trying to use an outlet with a component that's tightly coupled to the parent. There are multiple other ways to achieve what you want. You can use `*ngIf`, etc. for starters, but you can also dynamically inject the child component, that way you have a direct reference to it. I have an app with a component "registry" and depending on the data I get, an ID in the data maps to a component.

Comment: No problems at all, actually thank you for following up on the issue; well, they're not really tightly coupled, as basically the component in question is just a form used to add new clients to a database; what I'd like to do is to separate actions taken when the form is sent while rendered within the MatDialog from actions taken when the form is rendered within the router-outlet; the instance rendered within the MatDialog is useful for the user to insert new clients "on-the-fly" without leaving the main view, while the instance rendered in the router-outlet should actually redirect [...]

Comment: [...] to another route upon insertion. It's worth mentioning that the above mechanism should apply to different forms, the "Client" form is just an example. So the solution here would be to just pass an instance of the service through the router-outlet... which doesn't seem to be possible. I wonder why there's no mechanism in-place yet to do such thing in Angular, I can't think of this to be "that" exotic of a scenario. Or the other option is, the solution is actually way simpler and I'm just failing to see it, and you don't even need to pass services to components this way...

Answer (score 1):

I know the perceived solution is to create separate instances of the service class, but I don't think this is a good idea as it adds complications by changing the intended use case of service singletons.

However, if you require to have one service and one component, the easiest solution may be to add an additional parameter to the service methods so it knows the context as to which component instance is invoking it.

The flag for your component can come from the data object that can be passed inside the MatDialog. If the component is loaded through the router, the MatDialog data object will be `undefined`.

Component file that loads MatDialog

```
public openClientPopup(){
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ClientComponent, {
    //...dialog options,
    data: {
      isDialog: true
    }
  });
```

client.component.ts

```
private source: 'dialog' | 'router';
constructor(
  @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private data: { isDialog: boolean }
){
  // Assign the source based on whether the MatDialog data object exists
  this.source = !!this.data?.isDialog ? 'dialog' : 'router';
}

pushToChildService(data){
  this.comService.pushToChild(data, this.source);
}

pushToParentService(data){
  this.comService.pushToParent(data, this.source);
}
```

Then finally in your singleton service file.

```
@Injectable
export class ComService {

    pushToChild(data: ParentInput, source:'dialog'|'router') {
        // You now know the source of the data.
    }

    pushToParent(data: ChildInput, source:'dialog'|'router') {
        // You now know the source of the data.
    }

    // code to instantiate two observables, one for the parent to subscribe to and one for the child to subscribe to

}
```

If this makes your two service methods too complex, you can define four service methods (one for each case). Then in the component, use the MatDialog data flag to invoke the necessary method.